# what does Count *: 1 tell me?

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, parameters, prism, store

My question is related to Win Store App development with Prism/MVVM. I use a GridView with a couple of GridViewItems. On SelectionChanged of the GridView I catch the event to find out which of the GridViewItems was selected. A parameter is passed through to the ViewModel in this format:

```
Private Function ExecuteAction(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal parameter As Object) As Object Implements IAction.Execute
```

In a Command Window in VB.Net I have this (during a break in the program):

```html
>? parameter.addeditems
{<Windows Runtime type>}
    Count *: 1
    IsReadOnly *: False
    Item: In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.
    Interface View: Expanding will show discovered interfaces
```

I'm looking for the "addeditems" and there should (and there is?) one object in the addeditems list. But I cannot get to it with the command

```
parameter.addeditems(0)
```

neither can I get to it with

```
parameter.addeditems.item(0)
```

Does this have anything to do with the asterisk that is put behind the Count property of the parameter.addeditems?

How can I reach the value that was passed in the parameter?

Comment: Not sure if I get you correctly. parameter is of Object type. So you are probably looking for type casting. Please try DirectCast(parameter, ActualTypeYouPassed).addeditems

Comment: Thanks @VijayKP, this indeed was the problem. In my case I had to cast the parameter to SelectionChangedEventsArgs and that did the trick.